# Remove empty input from php message

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP form with some 'global' fields and 2 hidden divs with extra fields in the page. It is working fine, but I want to do an extra thing with it. I’ll try to explain.

For example, the global inputs are 'Name' and 'Email'. The extra div 1 has the inputs 'Quantity_of_div_1' and 'Color_of_div_1' and the extra div 2 has the inputs 'Quantity_of_div_2' and 'Color_of_div_2'.

So I wrote this code to send the form to my email (it’s just part of the code):

```
    <?php
          if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){
             require("js/funcoes_mail.php");

             $name     =  ValidarString($_POST[‘name’], "");
             $email     =  ValidarEmail($_POST['email']);
             $quantity_div_1     =  ($_POST['quantity_div_1']);
             $color_div_1     =  ($_POST['color_div_1']);
             $quantity_div_2     =  ($_POST['quantity_div_2’]);
             $color_div_2     =  ($_POST['color_div_2’]);

$msg = "<html>
            <head><title>SOMETHING</title></head>
            <body>
                            <DIV>
                                <table width=\"565\" height=\"auto\" border=\"0\">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <strong>Name</strong>: $name <br />
                                            <strong>E-mail</strong>: $email <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                    <tr id=\"msg_div_1\”>
                                        <td>
                                           <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_1 <br />
                                           <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_1 <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id=\"msg_div_2\”>
                                        <td>
                                           <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_2 <br />
                                           <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_2 <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </TABLE>
                            </DIV>
                        </body>
                    </html>";
?>
```

I have two buttons (href) that call a javascript function to dynamically add the extra divs. (Something like “Show div 1” and “Show div 2”).

So if the user click the link “Show div 2” the extra div is added and the user can fill the inputs.

My problem is, I don’t want to receive the `“<tr id=\"msg_div_1\”>”` in my mesage if it the user clicked and filled just the data of div 2 (and vice-versa).

How can I do that? I have tried a lot of ways but anything worked.

Comment: You do realize that your code contains many curly quotes `”` - `‘ ’` Are those part of your actual working code?

Comment: @Harutyun You edited OP's "code"; we cannot edit "code", but fix typos or indent. How do we know that is not what OP's code actually is? I'm doing a rollback. OP can edit his own code if that's what it is.

Comment: Hi Fred. Yes, its my working code. But dont worry about it. The code is working fine. I just want to 'filter' empty inputs before PHP send it to my email. (I dont want to receive them in the mesage).

Comment: Hi Adriano. OK. Well, that posted code should be throwing errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you will see what I mean. You should be using `'` and `"` for all quotes and not `“ ”` - `‘ ’` - are you using MS Word to edit code with?

Comment: Thanks Fred... I will check it out. And Im using Dreamweaver.

Comment: You're welcome. Dreamweaver, *hm...*, it might be the keyboard language then. Those curly quotes should not be used in code. Once you run your code, you will get an error for sure when error checking/reporting is used, which should be used.

Comment: Plus, who knows. Maybe what you did try and it did not work, may very well be the reason **why** it did not work. Use the standard quotes as I've noted above and try it again and see with what you tried.

Comment: Ok Fred. I will fix it and try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to do below 2 changes...

**Note:** Add validation to enter appropriate color / quantity input elements.

1. On the PHP mail body add if condition to check which data to send

**Modified PHP Code**

```
$msg = "<html>
            <head><title>SOMETHING</title></head>
            <body>
                            <DIV>
                                <table width=\"565\" height=\"auto\" border=\"0\">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <strong>Name</strong>: $name <br />
                                            <strong>E-mail</strong>: $email <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>";

if($quantity_div_1 != "" && $color_div_1 != "") {
    $msg .= "<tr id=\"msg_div_1\">
                                        <td>
                                           <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_1 <br />
                                           <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_1 <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>";
}

if($quantity_div_2 != "" && $color_div_2 != "") {
    $msg .= "<tr id=\"msg_div_2\">
                                        <td>
                                           <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_2 <br />
                                           <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_2 <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </TABLE>
                            </DIV>
                        </body>
                    </html>";
}
```

2. Using javascript,  clear respective quantity / color fields if opposite div event is fired.

**jQuery Code**

```
$("a.divSelector").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == "div1") {
        $("#quantity_div_2").val("");
        $("#color_div_2").val("");
    }else if($(this).attr('id') == "div2") {
        $("#quantity_div_1").val("");
        $("#color_div_1").val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Divakar. I just used the first part (PHP) of your answer. I was trying to put the "if" before the <tr> line. With the <tr> inside the "if" it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your form code here but (just guessing) you could try to build it on the fly:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);

// decide which values to add
if( showdiv1 )
{
  field0 = document.createElement("input");
  field0.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  field0.setAttribute("name", "q_div1");
  field0.setAttribute("value", quantity_of_div1 );

  form.appendChild( field0 );
}

form.submit();
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can check with empty() if the fields is empty or not and add a if statement to show it or not.

Also you can in your form just name it as array if you have more than this 2 like color_div_3...
and then you can do a loop on this.

### To fix your code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar') {
    require("js/funcoes_mail.php");

    $name           = ValidarString($_POST['name'], "");
    $email          = ValidarEmail($_POST['email']);
    $quantity_div_1 = (!empty($_POST['quantity_div_1'])) ? $_POST['quantity_div_1'] : false;
    $color_div_1    = (!empty($_POST['color_div_1'])) ? $_POST['color_div_1'] : false;
    $quantity_div_2 = (!empty($_POST['quantity_div_2'])) ? $_POST['quantity_div_2'] : false;
    $color_div_2    = (!empty($_POST['color_div_2'])) ? $_POST['color_div_2'] : false;

    $msg = "<html>
                <head><title>SOMETHING</title></head>
                <body>
                    <DIV>
                        <table width='565' height='auto' border='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong>Name</strong>: $name <br />
                                    <strong>E-mail</strong>: $email <br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>";
    if($quantity_div_1 || $color_div_1) {
        $msg .=                 "<tr id='msg_div_1'>
                                    <td>
                                       <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_1 <br />
                                       <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_1 <br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>";
    }

    if($quantity_div_2 || $color_div_2) {
        $msg .=                 "<tr id='msg_div_2'>
                                    <td>
                                       <strong>Quantity</strong>: $quantity_div_2 <br />
                                       <strong>Color</strong>: $color_div_2 <br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>";
    }

    $msg .=             "</TABLE>
                    </DIV>
                </body>
            </html>";
}
?>
```

### Something to think about

If you have more than 2 fields and you want to do this dynamic you can just use array in your form and check this array with loop in the php.

to do this more organized i add some js to handle the array in the form.

Something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['qandc'])) {
    foreach($_POST['qandc'] as $qandc) {
        $q = $qandc['quantity_div'];
        $c = $qandc['color_div'];
        if($q || $c) {
            echo 'quantity: '.$q;
            echo 'color: '.$c.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="clonethis">
        <input type="text" name="qandc[0][quantity_div]">
        <input type="text" name="qandc[0][color_div]">
    </div>
    <div class="clones">

    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-inputs">Add inputs</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNameID = 1;
    $('.add-inputs').click(function() {
        var clone = $('.clonethis').clone();
        clone.appendTo($('.clones'));
        $('.clones').find('.clonethis').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('clonethis');
            $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
                var existingName = $(this).attr('name');
                var newName = existingName .replace(/(\d+)+/g, function(match, number) {
                   return parseInt(newNameID);
                });
                $(this).attr('name', newName);
                $(this).val("");
            });
        });
        newNameID++;
    });
});
</script>
```